# Search with beautifulsoup for string inside table and print header

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a problem parsing a table with beautifulsoup. I want to search the table for a name, like "Smith". When a `<td>` with "Smith" is found, I want to get the head (`<th>`) in which column "Smith" was found AND the first tag in the row (`<tr>`) where Smith was found...

Another problem is: the tables does not always have the same width... I was working the whole day on it, tried thousands of different things and tricks from SO... :(

Someone could get me in the right direction please? :(

Regards,
Celvin

Comment: you need answer in JQuery ?

Comment: Uhm? No, in Python. I tought that was clear because of the tags. Sorry